# Angular $http returns "no access control allow origin" header, but jQuery $.get request returns information

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

How the heck can jQuery $.get, $.post and get desired results but angular can't $http.get, $http.post?  Why is the origin policy not working for angular but for jquery?

Laravel backend, angular front-end.  I'm considering just using jQuery because it doesn't prevent CRUD actions from happening on the client-side.

I configured $http and $httpProvider...

```
.run(function($http){
     $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*";
     $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
     $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Authorization";
})
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
})
```

And laravel is sending back the appropriate header...

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

So the weird thing is angular $http cannot get anything back from the server and produces this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/test. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But jQuery $.get and $.post work correctly!

```
$.post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/test', function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: +1 not sure why the downvotes, this isn't the typical xDomain problem

Comment: is your jQuery running from localhost:9000 (same place as angular) as well or is it some where else?

Comment: did you try on other browsers from what you are currently using? If there is any more information of the error on the console can you post it as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

Just setting `useXDomain` to true is not enough. AJAX request are also send with the `X-Requested-With` header, which indicate them as being AJAX. Removing the header is necessary, so the server is not rejecting the incoming request.

Try adding this within filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Request::getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        $headers = array(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',);
        return Response::make('', 200, $headers);
    }
});
```

It might be failing on the pre-flight request

Comment: There is no such thing as `useXDomain` in Angular. It never made into the Angular code. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2956